# Why does this function return 83 and not 5 when we call function(2)?

Tags: java, recursion

When I run this function by inputting 2 and I do not understand why it returns 83 and not 5 since it should call function(1) in the else statement and then the if statement should get executed and the function should return 5.

```java
public static int function(int y) {
    if (y == 1)
        return 5;
    
    function(y - 1);
    y = y + 1;
    
    return 83;
}
```

Comment: why you expect 5? it should return 83...

Answer (score 3):

It returns 83 because you are not using the return value of `function(y - 1);`
To test it try:

```
public static int function(int y) {
    if (y == 1)
        return 5;
    else {
        int returnedValue =  function(y - 1);
        System.out.println("un used returned value: "+returnedValue);
        y = y + 1;
        return 83;
    }
}
```

Change to:

```
public static int function(int y) {
   if (y == 1)  return 5;
   /*else*/ 
   return function(y - 1); 
}
```

Comment: Okay, I think I get it now, thank you!

Comment: Be careful, for `y < 1` this is infinite recursion

Answer (score 2):

With input: y = 2,

else condition will be handled.

```
function(y - 1);//nothing impact to y
y = y + 1;// y =3
return 83; // but finally return 83
```

Do you get the point?

Comment: But won't function(1) also be called in the else statement and that would lead to returning 5?

Comment: yeah, it return to 5 and the result is not assigned for any variable...  and continue to process below code... Please be aware, you should consider function(1) not relative to current context.

Comment: Okay got it thank you!

Comment: welcome ........

Answer (score 2):

Since you do not return `function(y-1)`, the statement is as good as making the function void (for that call).

So, as soon as the control reaches function(y-1) and eventually leads to calling function(1), you do get 5 but it is not returned to the driver function. What is instead returned is the value 83.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```java
public static int function(int y) {
    if (y == 1)
        return 5;
    
    function(y - 1);   // you do not use return value
    y = y + 1;

    return 83;         // you always get this return
}
```

It means that you can replace your function with:

```java
public static int function(int y) {
    return 83;
}
```

---

Looks like you want to do smth. like this:

```java
public static int function(int y) {
    return y == 1 ? 5 : function(y - 1);
}
```

but be careful, because for `y < 1` you will have an infinite recursion (`StackOverflowError`).

Comment: I would add that y value does not affect the result.